# Why can't both beakers have same temperature after some "finite time"?

Tags: temperature, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

There is this question in H.C Verma's book

> [image]

I have solved the question and got the right answer but analysing the answer indicates something weird.

Here's the answer of that question

> [image]

The answer indicates that the water in the smaller beaker can never reach the temperature $\theta_o$ in a finite time, which is really strange.

**So can someone explain why can't both beakers eventually have same temperature in a finite time ?**

Comment: Note that the result shows that while the beakers will not be the same temperature after any finite amount of time, their temperatures can be *arbitrarily close* after a finite amount of time. Since any possible measuring tool has finite precision, you will find the measured temperatures of both beakers to be identical after enough time. The temperatures will be "the same" to whatever experimental precision you desire after enough time, but theoretically never equal.

Answer (score 2):

Because the large beaker is maintained at a constant temperature, it acts as an energy reservoir. The rate of transfer of energy by heat through a homogeneous material is given by: $$P = \frac {kA(T_h-T_c)}{L}$$

where $T_h$ and $T_c$ represent temperatures of the hot and cold ends respectively.

From this equation, it is easy to discern that the rate of transfer of energy is in proportion to the difference in temperatures of the ends of the rod.

For your condition to be satisfied, we need $T_c \rightarrow T_h$ which suggests that $P \rightarrow 0$, so as the temperature of the water in the small beaker approaches that of the large beaker, the rate of transfer of energy becomes so minuscle that it effectively takes an infinite amount of time for it to finally reach thermal equilibrium with the energy reservoir (large beaker).

This is also shown by the result you've deduced. As $\theta_2 \rightarrow \theta_0$, $T \rightarrow \infty$

Note that this answer assumes that the system of the beakers and the rod are isolated and that there are no energy transfers into or out of the system by electromagnetic radiation or any other energy transfer mechanism. You can come close to acheiving this by insulating the rod and preventing the evaporation of water in the second beaker.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Both the problem and your answer ignore any convection losses (or radiation losses) from the rod while failing to mention insulation of the rod. Otherwise: good answer.

Comment: @Gert Thank you for pointing that out. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We know that the rate of heat transfer is proportional to the difference between the temperatures of the two vessel. And the rate of change of temperature of the smaller vessel is proportional to the rate of heat transfer (because the larger vessel is kept at a constant temperature $\theta_0$). So

$$\displaystyle \frac {d \theta_1}{dt} = k (\theta_0 - \theta_1(t))$$

for some constant $k$. We also have

$$\displaystyle \frac {d^2 \theta_1}{dt^2} = -k \frac {d \theta_1}{dt} $$

and so

$$\displaystyle \frac {d^2 \theta_1}{dt^2} \propto \theta_0 - \theta_1(t)$$

Continuing to differentiate, we find that all higher derivatives of $\theta_1(t)$ are also proportional to $\theta_0 - \theta_1(t)$.

If at some time $t$ we have $\theta_1(t) = \theta_0$ then *all* of the derivatives of $\theta_1(t)$ are zero at time $t$, in which case $\theta_1$ never changes, so $\theta_1(t) = \theta_0 \space \forall t$. So $\theta_1$ cannot pass through the value $\theta_0$ and we have three possible cases:

1. $\theta_1 > \theta_0 \space \forall t$
2. $\theta_1 < \theta_0 \space \forall t$
3. $\theta_1 = \theta_0 \space \forall t$

Answer (score -3):

After a very short time the difference between the two temperatures is equal for all measurements. The equation does not take into account the existence of atoms or molecules so, theoretically, you can say the time is infinite. In practice, you calculate how long it takes to have the difference below the limit of measuring.